# ui router with prerender.io (Middleware using Hapi Javascript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, prerender

how to use ui router with prerender.io by using  Hapi Javascript as a middleware

Example using this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IzimSVsstarlFviAm7S7?p=preview).

```
.state('about', {
  url: '/about',
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: 'partial-about.html'
    },
    'columnOne@about': {
      template: 'Look I am a column!'
    },
    'columnTwo@about': {
      templateUrl: 'table-data.html',
      controller: 'scotchController'
    }
  }
});
```

defined with multiple views can't able to get the render output  as expected in normal view

Comment: You shouldn't have any issues there. As long as it works in your browser, it should work on Prerender.io. Can you send us an email with the URL in question? We'll take a look at it! support@prerender.io

Comment: hi thank you for the comment but in my case a official page of ui router which was having the sample application was also can't be to render properly

Comment: @Prerender.io ., page shows up empty blank page can you suggest any workouts ?